# Cognito log UI stuck on Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I am developing a simple web application just to learn Android development using KOTLIN. I am implementing a log in feature using AWS Cognito service. But the app is stuck when I open cognito sign in UI.

This is my awsconfiguration.json

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "xxxx"
        "Region": "eu-west-2"
      }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager" : {
    "Default" : { }
  }
}
```

I created an Activity, in my activity, I open cognito sign in UI like this.

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this) {
            val signin = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(
                    this@LoginActivity,
                    SignInUI::class.java) as SignInUI
            signin.login(
                    this@LoginActivity,
                    MainActivity::class.java).execute()
        }.execute()
    }
}
```

When I run my app, it is stuck here. I cannot do anything. It is not displaying the log in UI as well.

[image]

What is missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess you're following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html ? Is there anything in logcat? Maybe it has no internet or something like that.

Comment: Thanks so much, mate